# Run a function periodically in Scala

Tags: scala, intervals, period

I want to call an arbitrary function every `n` seconds. Basically I want something identical to `SetInterval` from Javascript. How can I achieve this in Scala?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You could use standard stuff from `java.util.concurrent`:

```
import java.util.concurrent._

val ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)
val task = new Runnable { 
  def run() = println("Beep!") 
}
val f = ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
f.cancel(false)
```

Or `java.util.Timer`:

```
val t = new java.util.Timer()
val task = new java.util.TimerTask {
  def run() = println("Beep!") 
}
t.schedule(task, 1000L, 1000L)
task.cancel()
```

Comment: It's important to add a handler in case the task fails because of an exception.

Answer (score 27):

If you happen to be on Akka, [Scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/scheduler.html) is quite convenient for this:

```
val system = ActorSystem("mySystem", config)
// ...now with system in current scope:
import system.dispatcher
system.scheduler.schedule(10 seconds, 1 seconds) {
  doSomeWork()
}
```

There is also `scheduleOnce` for one-off execution.

The usual warnings about closing over mutable state apply.

Answer (score 9):

It can be more functional as in

```
    import java.util.TimerTask
    import java.util.Timer

    object TimerDemo {
      implicit def function2TimerTask(f: () => Unit): TimerTask = {
        return new TimerTask {
          def run() = f()
        }
      }

      def main(args : Array[String]) {
        def timerTask() = println("Inside timer task")

        val timer = new Timer()
        timer.schedule(function2TimerTask(timerTask),100, 10)

        Thread.sleep(5000)

        timer.cancel()

      }

    }
```

Comment: I like this solution, could you also provide an implimentation with a return value? i was thinking more like a counter down. how does `implicit def function2TimerTask(f: () => Unit): wrapper work with return value? Is this even a thing in functional

Answer (score 5):

Update for Akka, in combination with the "Hello World example" from here: [Lightbend Guides](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-scala/) using the instructions from here: [Scheduler](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scheduler.html?language=scala)

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

howdyGreeter ! WhoToGreet("Akka")

val cancellable =
system.scheduler.schedule(
  0 seconds,
  1 seconds,
  howdyGreeter,
  Greet
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please clarify where `system` is supposed to imported from?

Comment: System is a actorsystem