# How can my Apache Spark code emit periodic heartbeats?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, timer

I'm developing an Apache Spark job to run and I plan to deploy it as one stage in an [AWS Step Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html). Unfortunately the particular way that I wish to deploy it [isn't directly supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-service-integrations.html) by Step Functions at this time; however, Step Functions has an API for a generic Task that I can make use of. Essentially, once the task is started, it needs to periodically make a call to [sendTaskHeartbeat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/stepfunctions/AWSStepFunctionsClient.html#sendTaskHeartbeat-com.amazonaws.services.stepfunctions.model.SendTaskHeartbeatRequest-) and then on completion it needs to call [sendTaskSuccess](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/stepfunctions/AWSStepFunctionsClient.html#sendTaskSuccess-com.amazonaws.services.stepfunctions.model.SendTaskSuccessRequest-).

My Spark job is written in Scala, and I'm wondering what the best approach for running something on a timer is within the context of an Apache Spark job. I see from [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351186/run-a-function-periodically-in-scala) that I could make use of `java.util.concurrent` or perhaps `java.util.Timer`, but I'm not sure how the threading would work specifically in a Spark context. Since Spark is already doing a lot to distribute my code across each node I'm not sure if there are some hidden considerations I need to be weary of (i.e. I don't really want more than one instance of my timer, I want to make sure it stops when the sparky parts of my code complete, etc.

Is it safe to use a regular `Timer` in a Spark job? If I did something like this:

```scala
val timer = new Timer()
val task = new TimerTask {
    /* sendTaskHeartbeat */
}
timer.schedule(task, 1000L, 1000L)

val myRDD = spark.read.parquet(pathToParquetFiles)
val transformedRDD = myRDD.map( /* business logic */ )
transformedRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(config) andThen task.cancel
```

Would that be sufficient? Or is there a risk that this code would lose track of the `task` and `timer` objects by the time it reaches the `andThen`, due to the distribution across nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making use of a combination of a `java.util.Timer` and a [SparkListener](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListener.html). I instantiate the Timer on the `onJobStart` event (and only once, so `if (TIMER == null) { /* instantiate */ }`, because the onJobStart event seemingly can fire multiple times). And then I handle the completion activity on the `onApplicationEnd` event (which does only fire once). The reason I didn't use `onApplicationStart` was because it seemed like by the time I hooked in my listener to the Spark context, this event had already fired.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your implement is sufficient. The timer task will only run in the driver node. (as long as you do not include them in the RDD transformation)
Only thing need to be careful is error handling. Make sure the timer task getting terminated when the transformation throws an error. otherwise your job could stuck because of timer thread is still alive.