# Call a function every X seconds when activated - Scala

Tags: scala

I have a variable which is going to help me check if 10 seconds has passed.

```
private val currTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
private val time: Long = 10000
```

I want something where, if a function `foo` is called, it will reset `currTime` to be the current time. That's the easy part which I can do. The tough part, and part 2 of this, is that if `currTime` at any point exceeds `time`, I want to change a boolean (say `isHappy`) from true to false - this can be in a function called `bar`.

I come from C#, so i'm not sure how to do this - typically we'd use a dispatcher timer but i have no idea how to achieve this is Scala.

I've seen scheduler examples and fixed interval examples, but this is more of a moving target... a condition that can be met at any time.

In simpler terms, it's like having 2 `ints`. Int A and Int B. When the sum of A and B is over 10, a function is triggered. A and B are forever changing in different functions in that class. How can we create a trigger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run a function periodically in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351186/run-a-function-periodically-in-scala)

Comment: potentially partially. If `foo` is called and resets `currTime`, how will the timer know to continue waiting until `currTime` is > than `time`?